# skill on your own session

Tags: users, session

So I kind of (read: did) run

```
skill -STOP -u <username>
```

on my own session... and I don't have root privileges on the machine. Short of getting the sysadmin to restore things (he's away), is there any possibility to resolve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send it a continue-signal (-CONT). Or kill it completely with -15 or -9.

Comment: Done, thanks. I had to use a separate SSH session.